# Do javascript engines perform any optimization of multidimentional arrays?

Tags: javascript, performance, v8, ecmascript-5

I know that modern javascript engines create **hidden classes** behind the scenes, so it's [not recommended](http://code.google.com/apis/v8/design.html#prop_access) to change objects at runtime (if you have a large set of objects with same structure).

Has anyone heard about internal optimizations of two-dimentional arrays?

I create a two-dimentional array this way:

```
var map = [];
for (i = 0; i < 100000; i++) {
    map.push(Array(2));
}
```

I'm planning to break the nice structure like this:

```
map[100].push(/* third element! */)
```

Will this have a dramatic impact on performance?

Comment: You should try it out and benchmark

Comment: Looking at [this article](https://gamealchemist.wordpress.com/2013/05/01/lets-get-those-javascript-arrays-to-work-fast/), it seems that it will require a memcopy of that single array since it will no longer be able to store that array in continuous memory with the rest. It shouldn't disrupt any of the other arrays until the memory is defragmented. I doubt you will see any performance impact.

Answer (score 0):

V8 doesn't do any optimizations for multi-dimensional arrays, so there should be no measurable impact on performance there.

I can't speak for other JavaScript engines, but would find it surprising if the pattern you describe had negative impact anywhere. The kind of optimization you're talking about typically requires making assumptions and guarding them with checks. Given the highly dynamic nature of JavaScript arrays, this is brittle enough for one-dimensional arrays; checking any non-trivial property of two-dimensional arrays is probably just not worth the cost.